# How to Log IP Address for Inbound Connections in MySQL

Tags: mysql-5.5, log

Is there a way in MySQL 5.5 (on Redhat 6.x) to log the IP address from where a particular query has been run? And have that appear in the general log or even relay and bin logs? I am trying to track down the offending app server.

I googled around, and checked documentation but most of the discussion surrounded using IP Addresses as data in tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have shell access to the server on which mysql is running, you can use tcpdump + pt-query-digest. First, do a tcpdump with the appropriate switches necessary for pt-query-digest: tcpdump -i [your interface] port [3306,etc] -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt > tcpdump.out

Then, after you are done with your packet capture, do this:

pt-query-digest tcpdump.out --type=tcpdump --group-by=fingerprint --print --no-report

That will give you the raw digest of all queries and the hosts from which they originated. More information can be found at: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Mostly out of curiosity, I'm wondering why this is not a core feature in MySQL. Seems like it would be useful. WDYT?

Comment: While MySQL is much more feature-rich than it was in its pre-5.x days, it is still a pretty bare-bones RDBMS compared to Oracle, MS SQL, DB2, etc. Generally, the skill-sets of a senior-level MySQL DBA include Linux and networking. Generally, the first thing to do when looking trying to do something with MySQL is search the Internet for solutions (ie: Open source or proprietary software, or one-off scripts). You'll find that a basic knowledge of Bash-scripting is beneficial.

Comment: What then might be the proper avenue for requesting this as a feature? It is to report a "bug" at bugs.mysql.com ... ?

Comment: Yeah - [http://bugs.mysql.com/] (bugs.mysql.com) is where you'd put in such a request. They're not the most responsive -- I've watched hardcore bugs linger for 2-3 years... :)